# Roll dice and count arrays beginner

Tags: java, arrays

I want to make a simple program that rolls a dice 1000 times and counts the amount of times each number 1-6 appears. It works fine but there is an error at the end.Why is it happening?

```
public class diceRollerCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dice [] = new int[7]; 
        for(int x = 0 ; x <1000; x++ ) {
            ++dice [(int)(Math.random()*6+1)];
        }
        System.out.println("Number       Frequency" );  
        for(int index = 0; 1 < dice.length ; index++) {
            System.out.println(index + "            " + dice[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Number       Frequency
0            0
1            170
2            143
3            188
4            165
5            173
6            161
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at diceRollerCounter.main(diceRollerCounter.java:20)
```

Comment: What is the condition `1 < dice.length`?

Comment: Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error are *off-topic*. While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: @ChthonicProject So should I delete this post then?

Comment: @ÉananHalferty : My vote is for closing. By the way, I hope this is not going to dissuade you from using SO. It's a wonderful community, and once you get the hang of it, you will almost certainly love it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loop condition tests if `1` is less than `dice.length`, and it's always `true`.  But you keep incrementing `index` until it's off the end of the array.

Instead test if `index` is less than `dice.length`.

Incidentally, you may want to initialize `index` to `1`, so that you skip the output of the number `0` appearing with a frequency of `0`.

Comment: @Downvoter Please indicate how this post can be improved.

Comment: Thank you so much man. Pretty simple now when it's explained haha :)